# Use of Normal with layers and plots

Tags: plotting, neural-networks

In documentation of ConstantPlusLayer we find

```
net = NetChain[{ ElementwiseLayer[Sin], 
   ConstantPlusLayer["Biases" -> {1, 3, 5}]}]
Plot[net[{x, x, x}] // Normal, {x, -10, 10}]
```

What is the point of using Normal? The plot works perfectly without it

Comment: as an aside, "ConstantPlusLayer" is apparently not recognized by the stackexchange parser

Comment: Likely just a documentation error, but not a bad one since it is just an unnecessary addition.